# What UITraitCollection does systemLayoutSizeFittingSize: use?

Tags: ios8, uikit, adaptive-ui

What `UITraitCollection` does `-[UIView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:]` use, when it is not attached to view hierarchy? I think UIKit could guess it from `[UIScreen mainScreen]`, but this looks ambiguous to me. Moreover, it will not take into account override in `-[UIViewController setOverrideTraitCollection:forChildViewController:]`.